# Dynamically populating query string in a href tag

Tags: php, get, query-string, dynamically-generated

I would like to pose a question. I have an index.php file that dynamically populates all chapters contained in the database.
My code is this :

```
foreach($chapters_titles as $title){
     echo  "<a href='index.php?chapter_id=1>". $title ['title']."</a>";
}

foreach($chapter_contents as $content){
     echo  "<br/>". $content;
}
```

I want to be able to see each chapter's sub-chapters when I click on the chapters title and sub-chapter's content when I click on the sub-chapter.
How can I achieve that?

I know that at the top of the page i'll have a block of code like

```
if(isset($_GET['chapter_id'])){
     code
}

if(isset($_GET['sub-chapter_id'])){
     code
}
```

I would really appreciate any pointer.

Comment: Note that the colorization of your question points at syntax errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Like bounce to an anchor link, or have it hidden but then appear on the screen by using javascript?

Comment: I want to display the chapter's sub-chapter by clicking on the chapter title...